# How do I keep radio buttons checked on pagination

Tags: php, ajax

In a quiz page of a website I'm building, I'm using ajax pagination to load in questions with multiple choices (only one of which is correct) from a MYSQL database.

The problem I'm facing is, whenever I go to another page and switch back, all radio buttons are unchecked.

This is a sample code of a quiz question:

```
<div class='quiz-item'>
    <p class='question'>question</p>
    <label for='questionID-A' class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='questionID' id='questionID-A' class='radio-input'>
        optionA
    </label>
    <label for='questionID-B' class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='questionID' id='questionID-B' class='radio-input'>
        optionB
    </label>
    <label for='questionID-C' class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='questionID' id='questionID-C' class='radio-input'>
        optionC
    </label>
    <label for='questionID-D' class='radio'>
        <input type='radio' name='questionID' id='questionID-D' class='radio-input'>
        optionD
    </label>
</div>
```

Is there any way to keep them checked?

Comment: This possible but you may need save the current state of the checkbox in the local storage as cookies or as another entry in the database. Using the local storage is recommended. You can attach a click event listener to the input or checkbox and trigger a function that saves a certain cookie associated with that checkbox.

Comment: Since I'm a stranger to cookies, may I get an example code on how to save/load cookies in my example?

Comment: I suggest you save it in the local storage, but you should clear the local storage after you finish the quiz.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#example

Comment: This is a basic example. https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-bush-8pykr?file=/src/index.js Unfortunately. The sandbox does not allow saving of cookies, so you may need to transfer it in your local installation.